# How to connect to couchbase databse using spring data couchbase and yaml properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring-data-couchbase in my spring boot application to connect to couchbase database and using application.ymal file to configure all the data source.  What is connection string for couchbase database and what configuration I have to do to connect to different environments like dev and prod ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an **application-dev.yml** file for your development environment and an **application-prod.yml** file for your production environment. In each file, you can specify the appropriate Couchbase connection string and other properties like this:

```
# application-dev.yml
spring:
  data:
    couchbase:
      connectionString: couchbase://localhost/mybucket
      username: myuser
      password: mypassword


# application-prod.yml
spring:
  data:
    couchbase:
      connectionString: couchbase://prod.example.com/mybucket
      username: produser
      password: prodpassword
```

For example, to activate the **dev** profile, you can run your application like this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

And to activate the **prod** profile, you can run it like this:

```
java -jar myapp.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

in a dev environment-config-

```
//the bucket you want to store data have dev-bucket

{
   "couchbase": 
{
   "connectionString": "couchbase://dev-server/dev-bucket",
   "username": "development user name",
   "password": "development password"
}
}
```

for production config profile environment

```
{
   "couchbase": {
   "connectionString": "couchbase://prod-server/prod-bucket",
   "username": "production user name profile",
   "password": "production user profile-password"
}
}
```